# ¿Como cambiar el color de fondo de una ventana en C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hola amigos tengo una duda;

Hay alguna forma de cambiar el color de fondo (o de letra) de un elemento pero de forma Hexadecimal en C#?

Ejemplo: **#007BFF**
Este es el código que yo estoy utilixando:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();

        Ventana.Background = Brushes.LightGray; //Justo aquí es donde se define el color de la ventana
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo consigues con una funcion que es parte de la clase `Color`: **Color.FromHex(str)**.

En tu caso especifico seria:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
        Ventana.Background = Color.FromHex("007BFF"); 
    }
}
```

Nota: Como puedes ver no se usa el signo de #.

Espero esto te ayude.-

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tu respuesta! El problema está en que ese código es para Xamarin Forms; Yo estoy usando Xamarin para aplicaciones de Windows.

Comment: OK, so al parecer eso no es Xamarin me parece que lo que estas usando es UWP el cual tiene un set de APIs distintas a Xamarin.

Comment: Sí así es amigo, y no sé como hacerlo